# extract dataframe from dataframe column an place it besides parent in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, unnest

I have a dataframe consisting on 10 columns, one of them is another dataframe as a result of a rowwise() operation.

something like this (just an example, column2 is a dataframe not in a list):

```
   id   column1   column2
    1213   a         df
    2234   b         df
    4565   c         df

class(df$column2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

So, the data is grouped by row (see rowwise() in tidyverse site) and the issue is I want to extract the column2 dataframe and place it besides the rest of columns.as they have the same number of rows.

The usual tidyr::unnest() approach gives one error:

```
 unnest(c, cols = c(column2))
Error: Assigned data `map(data[[col]], as_df, col = col)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 24356 rows.
x Assigned data has 124 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

So I have extracted the column2 into another dataframe and then dplyr::bind_cols() but This is very dirty and I guess if there is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can try with

```
cbind(df[1:2], do.call(rbind, df$column2))
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df[1:2], bind_rows(df$column2))
```

and `tidyr` -

```
tidyr::unnest_wider(df, column2)

#    id column1   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  1213 a          21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#2  2234 b          21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#3  4565 c          21     6   160   110   3.9  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
```

**data**

Tested all the answers on this data -

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1213L, 2234L, 4565L), column1 = c("a", 
"b", "c"), column2 = list(structure(list(mpg = 21, cyl = 6, disp = 160, 
    hp = 110, drat = 3.9, wt = 2.62, qsec = 16.46, vs = 0, am = 1, 
    gear = 4, carb = 4), row.names = "Mazda RX4", class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(mpg = 21, cyl = 6, disp = 160, hp = 110, drat = 3.9, 
        wt = 2.62, qsec = 16.46, vs = 0, am = 1, gear = 4, carb = 4), row.names = "Mazda RX4", class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(mpg = 21, cyl = 6, disp = 160, hp = 110, drat = 3.9, 
        wt = 2.62, qsec = 16.46, vs = 0, am = 1, gear = 4, carb = 4), row.names = "Mazda RX4", class = "data.frame"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```